# Problems with saving to a file in processing

Tags: file, save, processing

I have a small problem with saving files in processing. The program saves everything, but when you close the program and open it again, the file is reset to zero and records are kept from the beginning. As I understand it, this is all due to the fact that the file is created again when you open the program. does anyone know how to open an already created file and write to it?

I'll attach the part with initialization:

```java
    void setup() { 
        size(330, 450);// создаем рабочее окно размером 800х600 точек
        surface.setTitle("Передача данных");//подпись вверху экрана
        printArray(Serial.list());//выводим активные порты на экран или монитор
        port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);//выбираем порт но ето не точно
        //работа с файлами
        cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
        front = loadFont("TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT-20.vlw");//подгружаем шрифт
        output0 = createWriter("POST1.txt");//создаем файл для логов с поста 1
        output1 = createWriter("POST2.txt");// создаем файл длялогов с поста два
        
        //создание списков
        cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
        p1 = cp5.addDropdownList("Post 1")//выпадающий список для поста 1
        .setPosition(100,100);//положение (x,y)
        p1.addItem(c11,c11);//пункты выпадающегосписка
        p1.addItem(c12,c12);
        p1.setColorBackground(color(60));
        p1.setColorActive(color(255, 128));
         
        p2 = cp5.addDropdownList("Post 2")//те же шаги но для списка 2
        .setPosition(100,150);
        p2.addItem(c11,c11);
        p2.addItem(c12,c12);
        p1.setColorBackground(color(60));
        p1.setColorActive(color(255, 128));
        
        //customize(p1);
        //customize(p2);
        }
```

The part in which the click on the dropdown list is processed after which it is written to the file:

```java
    void controlEvent(ControlEvent theEvent){
      String name = theEvent.getName();
      float value = theEvent.getController().getValue();
      int i = 0;
      if(name.startsWith("Post 1")){
        if(value==0.0){
          //data = loadStrings("POST1.txt");
           println("test code0");
           selection.println("test code0" + " " + day()+"."+month()+"."+year()+" "+hour()+":"+minute()+":"+second());
           //("POST1.txt");
           output0.flush();
           //output0.close();
           //exit();
         }  
        if(value==1.0){
          println("test code1");
          output0.println("test code1" + " " + day()+"."+month()+"."+year()+" "+hour()+":"+minute()+":"+second());
          output0.flush();
          output0.close();
          exit();
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, calling `createWriter` with the same name as the existing file will overwrite the file with a new blank file, ready for output. So you'll need to read the file (if it exists) into your sketch before creating the output writer.

The counterpart to `createWriter` is [`createReader`](https://processing.org/reference/createReader_.html). The [reference](https://processing.org/reference/createReader_.html) shows an example of how to read a file and parse the contents.

In that example, they simply draw the contents to the screen. That might work for you, or you may need to store the contents in your sketch (in an array or other data structure) until you're ready to write the data back out to the file (with any modifications that have been made).

Depending on what exactly you're trying to save and load, you might look at [saveJSONObject](https://processing.org/reference/saveJSONObject_.html) and [loadJSONObject](https://processing.org/reference/loadJSONObject_.html). It can make loading and parsing the file easier if you're working with more complex data structures.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried to write data to a JSON file, but I didn't quite understand how to make it write new data, and not overwrite existing ones. Just in my program, data is recorded by clicking on it. I had an idea to change the record id by incrementing the counter, but it didn't work and so I gave it up. After a huge number of tests I decided to create an additional file in which I will copy the data I already have and then write it back to the original file after it is recreated